# Smallest ideal containing elements is the generated ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I want to show these:

> (a) Let $x_1,x_2,..., x_n$ be elements of a commutative ring R. Show that the ideal generated by $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ is the smallest ideal contain $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$.
>
> (b) Conclude that the ideal generated by $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ is the intersection of all ideals that contain $x_1, x_2,. . ., x_n$

a) $ (x_1,x_2,....,x_n)={r_1x_1+r_2x_2+......+r_nx_n} $

- $0=0x_1+0x_2+.....+0x_n$ , $0\in I $
- let $a={r_1x_1+r_2x_2+......+r_nx_n} , b={r_{11}x_1+r_{22}x_2+......+r_{nn}x_n} $

$a-b={(r_1-r_{11})x_1+(r_2-r_{22})x_2+......+(r_n-r_{nn})x_n} $,then $a-b\in I$

- let $r \in R , a\in I $
  $ra={rr_1x_1+rr_2x_2+......+rr_nx_n} $, then $ra\in I $
- so it is ideal

In this part, I show it is ideal but I don't know how to show that is smallest ideal.

b) I know if it is smallest ideal then all ideal of $R$ contains $I$, but how to prove it?

Comment: Let $I$ be some ideal containing $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and show that $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\subset I$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any ideal $I$ containing your $n$ elements.
Then take any element $y$ in the ideal $J$ generated by the elements.
Using the properties of an ideal, can you show that $y\in I$ (so that $J\subset I$)?
This should be straightforward once you write out what you want.
(You seem to have the calculation mostly there, what is missing is reasoning.)
The conclusion is that any ideal $I$ containing your elements contains $J$ as a subideal.
Therefore $J$ is the smallest possible ideal.

For part (b), use part (a).
Show the inclusion both ways: the intersection contains the generated ideal and vice versa.
One of the directions needs part (a).

Comment: Prove like this ? Assume $J= {y_1,y_2,....y_n} $ is an ideal and. $I $is ideal  generated by element .let $y \in  J $ and $r \in I $
Then $ry\in J $then $I\subset j $

Comment: @user508518 Any element $y\in J$ is of the form $y=r_1x_1+\dots+r_nx_n$. Since $I$ is an ideal, $x_i\in I$ implies $r_ix_i\in I$. The ideal is also closed under sums, so $y\in I$.